# windows 8.1: 2 folders with same name and includes in folder section

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-libraries

I have problem with folder section in my windows 8.1, there are two folders having the same name and includes while it should be named `pictures` and `videos` with different contents as in Libraries folders.

Check screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You may want to try [this guide to restore the locations](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18583-user-folders-restore-default-location.html). Maybe it helps with naming too.

Comment: @ap0 I had tried all steps mentioned in your link but nothing could separate the two folders from being the same!